# C# Selenium Upload Byte array instead of File

Tags: c#, html, arrays, selenium, webdriver

I would like to see if its possible to submit a FileStream (instead of a File) into an HTML Input, using Selenium.

Scenario is that i need to automate the upload of files, but those files should not be ever saved in the machine, hence the usage of Byte Array.

I cannot use http Request due to the complex authentication of the WebPortal. That-s why the use of Chrome WebDriver.

```
private Tuple<bool, string> UploadFile(string fileName, byte[] fileContentClear, Customer destCustomer)
{
    //chrome definition
    //Selenium login into the portal and opening the Html File browser

    //Select and submit file
    string theFilePath = file.Replace('/', '\\'); //need to put backslash the filepath, else will fail
    browser.FindElement(By.XPath(GetFileBtnXpath)).SendKeys(file); //insert the path in input box
    //file will be a byteArray 
    IWebElement uploadAndSubmitButton = browser.FindElement(By.XPath(uploadSubmitBtnXpath));
    uploadAndSubmitButton.Click(); //submit the file
}
```

Comment: As IWebElement are just abstractions over the HtmlElements in the actual browser and as far as I know no browser supports accepting an FileStream or bytearray I have doubts if this is possible. Even if I would hook into the browser directly I doubt you can make an file input do that.